# How to convert NSArray to String array to use results in a UITableView? or change JSON query to suit

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I have a function (below) that sends an API request to my database and retrieves an array of names from my database.

The `print (json)` command currently outputs the following:

> Optional(["names": <__NSArrayI 0x618000226e40>(
>   Dicky Downs,
>   Steve Downs
>   )
>   ])

the `print (arr)` command outputs:

> (
>       "Dicky Downs",
>       "Steve Downs"
>   )

I would like to put these results into a string array that I can then use in a UITableView.  At the moment they are in an NSArray.

I don't know why but it seems the JSON is sending them this way?  In my other API calls they come back as Strings.???

This is the swift script:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let myUrl = URL(string: "http://www.quasisquest.uk/KeepScore/specificCommunity.php?");
    var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!);
    request.httpMethod = "POST";
    let postString = "id=\(comIds[communityId!])";

    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);


    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

        DispatchQueue.main.async
            {

                if error != nil {
                    print("error=\(error)")
                    return
                }

                do{
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject]
                   print (json)
                    if let arr = json?["names"] as? NSArray {
                        print (arr)

                    }



                } catch{
                    print(error)
                }
        }
        }
    task.resume()


}
```

This is the PHP database call:

```
$communityPlayerNames = array();
$communityPlayerNames = $dao->getPlayerNames($getIds);

public function getPlayerNames($player_ids)
{
$returnValue = array();

$sql = "SELECT user_name\n"
. "FROM users\n"
. "WHERE id IN ( ".$player_ids.")";

  $result = $this->conn->query($sql);
    if($result != null && (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1)){
while($row = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
   if(!empty($row)){
      $returnValue[] = $row['user_name'];
   }
}
}
    return $returnValue;
}

echo json_encode(array('names' => $communityPlayerNames));
```

Two questions then:
1) Can I use an NSArray in a UITableView?
2) If not, how do I convert it to a String Array?

Comment: `if let arr = json?["player_names"] as? [String]` Your log says it's a array of string, not an array of dictionary.

Comment: Can you try to print the actuall result from server and show us ?

Comment: @UmairAfzal I've updated the question with the latest amendments and progress

Comment: @RDowns I was not asking for server side code. I am asking for full JSON which is being returend. In other words., what do you get when you print (json) ???

Comment: that's in the post. The first yellow block

Comment: if let arr = json?["names"] as? [String] try this.

Comment: Hahah I can't believe it was that easy! I've had 2 hours of this! I've already had answers that have since been deleted because we weren't getting a full solution (though some progress was made) Thanks Umair!